# Is it possible to re-write this class without using "this is"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-6.0

I reviewed this code and I want to refactor keeping the same logic without using **this is**

```cs
class Animal
{
    public void Verify()
    {
        if (this is Animal) {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal");
        } else if (this is Person) {
            Console.WriteLine("Person");
        } else if (this is Home) {
            Console.WriteLine("Home");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("*******");
        }
    }
}
class Person
...
class Home
...
```

Comment: (GetType() == typeof(Animal)

Comment: this will always print "Animal" though.

Comment: This looks like a job for an interface, not for a sequence of `else if`s.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an inheritance hierarchy here? I can't see how `this is Animal` would ever be false.

Answer (score 3):

It probably counts as too similar, but `switch (this)` using "pattern matching" i.e. `case Person:` might be an option, however IMO a better approach here would be polymorphism, so: have a `virtual` or `abstract` method in the base class, and `override` it as suitable in each sub-class. Now polymorphism deals with the selection for you.

Comment: sorry, could you write an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a little bit of reflection:

```
    Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);
```